# How to make an specific website compatible with another browser?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, browser

I am just getting into the world of programming and websites and I have an specific question I hope won't bother you. I am building a website (elcamal.com) and I'm concerned with the fact that I only tested and designed in Chrome, but now that I tested in Firefox, Safari and IE, it's totally ruined, specially in Safari.

It seems that the problems are not so bad, it's just some issues with the grid.

What would be the first steps to make my web compatible with at least Firefox and Safari? I would like to know if it's something that I can learn or if I need to hire someone.

Thanks for your patience and have a good day.

Comment: You should check each browser on development phase.

Comment: That's called Cross Browser Compatibility

Comment: You have to use standard CSS features and JS API's, and avoid hacks or  vendor prefixes. I agree with the last comment, you should have checked since the beginning is harder to fix bugs when the project is complete.

Comment: I continue the notion that you *should* have checked cross browser compatibility during development. That said, what are the errors? Does  this "grid" simply not function, not display properly, etc etc. These are the questions you need to ask your self so you can start working on debugging.

Comment: I've just found "the words" to explain the problem. It's the floats.

Answer (score 2):

To make your website Cross Browser Compatible you need keep lots of thing in mind. Some points are below:-

1. Try to use **standard CSS features**.Each tag is properly taken care.
2. Try to avoid hacks to achieve something.(howeversometime we need to use hack to fix something but make them minimal).
3. Try to use conditional comments instead of CSS hacks. With conditional comments you can link to separate style sheets for different browsers.

   `<!--[If IE]><link type="text/css" href="IEtest.css" />   <![endif]-->`
4. **Testing** play important role you should check since the beginning of development in major browsers.
5. Imp:-**Clear Your Floats**. This refers to divs which serve as containers to other divs and should wrap around them but sometimes don’t.
6. Try to use **javascript library** like jQuery, YahooUI, MooTools, Dojo abstract away the differences in the DOM, AJAX and JavaScript.
7. Define **Valid Doctype**.
8. Enable HTML 5 in major browsers:- When working with HTML5 we need to include the "HTML5 shiv" to ensure that CSS will recognize and be able to style those elements in browsers that aren't yet hip to HTML5.

   `<!--[if IE]><script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->`

You will find some good point by yourself while developing the page. Try to Google.

Comment: Isn't a conditional comment a sort of hack too?

Comment: @MrLister: I agree, yes it is hack, as I mentioned above((however sometime we need to use hack to fix something but make them minimal).

Comment: Hello and thanks for your responses, I've managed to make the website work for firefox but safari 7.0 is still ruined. The problem are the floats, everything looks centered in safari. Any advice?

Comment: yes clear the float by using clear: both, hope it works